# dependent types with variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic, dependent-name

Can you see anything wrong with this function declaration?

```
template<typename... Containers>
std::tuple<typename Containers::value_type...>
foo(const Containers &...args);
```

When I try to call it, like this:

```
foo(std::list<int>(), std::vector<float>());
```

MSVC2013 says `error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::tuple<Containers::value_type>`.

I tried rewriting the function declaration with the "late return" syntax and it made no difference.

Is there any way I can achieve what this code is trying to do?

Comment: Did you forget to `#include <tuple>` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won the right to fill a bug report on microsoft [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)… The code is ok on clang and gcc.

A workaround on VS2013 and maybe gcc 4.7 :

```
template <typename T>
using ValueType = typename T::value_type;

template<typename... Containers>
std::tuple<ValueType<Containers>...>
foo( const Containers &...args ) { return {}; }
```

Comment: Not on my version of gcc. Which are you using? I get a weird error on gcc 4.7.2, asking me to file a bug report.

Comment: g++ 4.8.2, c++11 is really something not as stable as old plain c++ and compiler evolve fast http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e554d0c9b837df67

Comment: Yeah I know. I've had issues with advanced templates and 4.7.2 before, but my distro doesn't have 4.8.x in its repository yet...

Comment: You may try the workaround i had in the answer, it is ok in VS2013

Comment: Compiles in gcc 4.7.2 as well, nice one.

Comment: Why typename in the tuple.

Comment: @Yakk a copy paste typo…

Comment: Thanks galop1n: your workaround has got me out of trouble.  Also I've reported to Microsoft, bug ID 816850.