# more dependent types with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, dependent-name

This follows [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607167/dependent-types-with-variadic-templates), where I gave some C++ code that Visual Studio 2013 couldn't handle, and @galop1n kindly provided a workaround, which worked perfectly for that case.  But now I've gone a tiny bit further and Visual Studio is giving me grief again.

```
template <typename T>
using ValueType = typename T::value_type;

template<typename... Containers>
void
foo(const Containers &...args) {
    std::tuple<ValueType<Containers>...> x;
}

template<typename... Containers>
struct Foo {
    std::tuple<ValueType<Containers>...> x;
};
```

Whenever I try to instantiate either function template foo or class template Foo, I get these two messages:

> Test.cpp(21): error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand

and

> Test.cpp(21): error C3203: 'ValueType' : unspecialized alias template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Types', expected a real type

In each case (instantiating foo or instantiating Foo), both messages point to the line that defines "x".

UPDATE: My [Microsoft bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816850/dependent-types-with-variadic-templates) now has (in its attachment) all the basic variants of this problem.  So that would be the place to watch for a fix.

Comment: Man you're just in suck-land, once again, *Both* work flawless on my Mac clang (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn). ugh. I don't have my VS2013 up and running so save me some typing and tell me, does VS2013 support template-template parameters? if so, there may be another work-around (at least from me, someone else may have other ideas as well, obviously). Edit: scratch that, not going to work how I wanted. yuck.

Comment: Maybe using a classic meta-function instead of a type alias might work, e.g. `template<typename T> struct value_type { typedef typename T::value_type type; };`

Comment: @pmr, you define "type" with a typedef inside a template class, which is the same way that the containers define "value_type"; so the problem for application code accessing your "type" is essentially the same problem over again, right?

Comment: @slyqualin Yes, you don't get the benefits of `using` declarations and will have to write `typename` all over the place, but it might convince the broken piece of technology you are using to actually let the code compile.

Comment: @pmr I wouldn't mind writing `typename` all over the place, except that's how I got into trouble in [the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607167/dependent-types-with-variadic-templates).

Comment: @slyqualin Yeah, I guess that despite being marketed this way you will simply have to accept that VS2013 does not support variadic templates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following works on VS2013 (more verbose :/ ):

```
template<typename... Containers>
void foo(const Containers &...args) {
    std::tuple<typename std::decay<decltype(*args.begin())>::type...> x;
}

template<typename... Containers>
struct Foo {
    std::tuple<typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<Containers>().begin())>::type...> x;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but you see this, like @pmr's solution, repeats the idiom that got me into strife in my [first posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607167/dependent-types-with-variadic-templates), i.e. it's using an expression of the form `std::tuple<typename BlahBlah::some_type ...>`.  If VS2013 undestood _that_, then I would have been a happy man long ago.  :)

Comment: Btw, the verbosity doesn't worry me, considering that my best workaround so far is to repeat my template for 1 arg, 2 args, 3 args and 4 args.